# I can't solve this

Tags: python

Hello I was creating a discord custom status changer here is the code I kept getting the error indentationerror: unindent does not match any outer indent

this is what it looks like in terminal

File "status.py", line 46
if choice == ("watching"):
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

here's the code

````
import os
import colorama
import time
from colorama import Fore


print("status are competing, playing, streaming, listening, watching ")
token = input(Fore.GREEN + "Token: ")


class MyClient(discord.Client):
 async def on_ready(self):
      print(Fore.CYAN + "Wait")
time.sleep(5)
print(Fore.GREEN + "Logged in as", self.user)




def playing():
 a = input("Text to display: ")
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=a5))

def streaming():
 a4 = input("Text to display: ")
u1 = input("Twitch account to display: ")
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=a4, url=u1))

def listening():
 a3 = input("Text to display: ")
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=a3))

def watching():
 a2 = input("Text to display: ")
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=a2))

choice = input("Status: ")



if choice == ("playing"):
        os.system("cls")
        def playing():
 
 if choice == ("watching"):
   os.system("cls")
   def watching():
    
 if choice == ("listening"):
        os.system("cls")
        listening():
    
 if choice == ("streaming"):
        os.system("cls")
        streaming():

client = MyClient()
client.run(token, bot=False)```
````

Comment: as indicated by the error message your indentation is wrong.

Comment: your indentation is wrong, it looks like there is an extra space in front of your final 3 if statements. If you remove that it should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove spaces in front of your last three if statements. Python is very strict about indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the functions again in your code where you should just call the function. Also check the indentations and remove some of the code that doesn't do anything.
The code comes because you are not using the proper indentation.
See this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/